# Select SDO_GEOMETRY line vertices as rows -- using recursive WITH clause

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-18c, geometry

I have an Oracle 18c table that has an SDO_GEOMETRY column (lines):

```
create table a_sdo_geometry_tbl (line_id integer, shape mdsys.sdo_geometry);

insert into a_sdo_geometry_tbl (line_id, shape) 
values (1, sdo_geometry (2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,2,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (671539.6852734378,4863324.181436138, 671595.0500703361,4863343.166556185, 671614.013553706,4863350.343483042, 671622.2044153381,4863353.525396131))  );

insert into a_sdo_geometry_tbl (line_id, shape) 
values (2, sdo_geometry (2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,2,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (71534.5567096211,4863119.991809748, 671640.7384688659,4863157.132745253, 671684.8621150404,4863172.022995591))  );

insert into a_sdo_geometry_tbl (line_id, shape) 
values (3, sdo_geometry (2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,2,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (671622.2044153381,4863353.525396131, 671633.3267164109,4863357.846229106, 671904.0614077691,4863451.286166754))  );

insert into a_sdo_geometry_tbl (line_id, shape) 
values (4, sdo_geometry (2002, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,2,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (671684.8620521119,4863172.022995591, 671892.1496144319,4863244.141440067, 671951.2156571196,4863264.824310392, 671957.4471461186,4863266.847617676, 671966.8243856924,4863269.146632658))  )
```

---

```
select
    line_id,
    sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(shape) as well_known_text
from
    a_sdo_geometry_tbl;

   LINE_ID    WELL_KNOWN_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1    LINESTRING (671539.685273438 4863324.18143614, 671595.050070336 4863343.16655619, 671614.013553706 4863350.34348304, 671622.204415338 4863353.52539613)         
                                                                                
         2    LINESTRING (71534.5567096211 4863119.99180975, 671640.738468866 4863157.13274525, 671684.86211504 4863172.02299559)                                             
                                                                                
         3    LINESTRING (671622.204415338 4863353.52539613, 671633.326716411 4863357.84622911, 671904.061407769 4863451.28616675)                                            
                                                                                
         4    LINESTRING (671684.862052112 4863172.02299559, 671892.149614432 4863244.14144007, 671951.21565712 4863264.82431039, 671957.447146119 4863266.84761768, 671966.824385692 4863269.14663266)                                                       
                                                                                
4 rows selected.
```

---

For each line, I want to select each vertex as a separate row in a query/resultset.

I want to do this via a **recursive WITH clause** -- without using the GetVertices() function or a custom TYPE.

Is there a way to do that?

---

The resultset would look like this:

```
   LINE_ID  VERTEX_ID          X          Y
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 671539.685 4863324.18
         1          2 671595.050 4863343.17
         1          3 671614.014 4863350.34
         1          4 671622.204 4863353.53

         2          1 71534.5567 4863119.99
         2          2 671640.738 4863157.13
         2          3 671684.862 4863172.02

         3          1 671622.204 4863353.53
         3          2 671633.327 4863357.85
         3          3 671904.061 4863451.29

         4          1 671684.862 4863172.02
         4          2 671892.150 4863244.14
         4          3 671951.216 4863264.82
         4          4 671957.447 4863266.85
         4          5 671966.824 4863269.15
```

Hints:

The following functions might be useful:

[PointN:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412038/135445) Returns a point that is the nth vertex in the collection of vertices

[GetNumVertices:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-DDC2B085-6A89-47F4-AADA-E7D9B00E00B4) Returns the number of vertices in the input geometry.

---

Comment: Related: [Generate rows in query for each number in integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993575/generate-rows-in-query-for-each-number-in-integer)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Use the WELL_KNOWN_TEXT function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  LINE_ID,
  ROUND(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE, '[^ - ]+', 1, 1 )),10) AS X,
  ROUND(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE, '[^ - ]+', 2, 1 )),10) AS Y
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      LINE_ID,
      TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS VALUE
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          LINE_ID,
          REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTR(WELL_KNOWN_TEXT,12),'(',''),')','') STR
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              LINE_ID,
              SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE) AS WELL_KNOWN_TEXT
            FROM
              A_SDO_GEOMETRY_TBL
          )
      )
      CONNECT BY INSTR(STR, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  )
ORDER BY  LINE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 2:**

Use spatial functions, including a custom PointN function, but not including the Get_Vertices function:

```
--Custom PointN fucntion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412038/135445
create or replace function cust_pointn (g sdo_geometry, n number)
return sdo_geometry
as
begin
  return (
    sdo_geometry (
      2001,
      g.sdo_srid,
      sdo_point_type (
        g.sdo_ordinates((n-1) * 2 + 1),
        g.sdo_ordinates((n-1) * 2 + 2),
        null
      ),
      null,
      null
    )
  );
end;
/

--Generate rows for each vertex using recursive WITH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65993625/10936066
with  rcte (line_id, vertex_id, num_vertices) as (
      select line_id, 1 as vertex_id, sdo_util.getnumvertices(shape) as num_vertices
      from a_sdo_geometry_tbl
      where sdo_util.getnumvertices(shape) > 0
      union all
      select line_id, vertex_id + 1, num_vertices
      from rcte
      where vertex_id < num_vertices
     )

--1. Select from the recursive WITH; has rows for each vertex
--2. Join to the original table to get the shape/line column
--3. Use the custom function to get the vertex shape/point (since I couldn't figure out how to include the shape column in the recursive WITH query)
--4. get the x and y from the vertex shape/point
select 
    a.line_id, 
    a.vertex_id,
    cust_pointn(shape,a.vertex_id) as vertex_point_shape,
    cust_pointn(shape,a.vertex_id).sdo_point.x as x,
    cust_pointn(shape,a.vertex_id).sdo_point.y as y
from 
    rcte a
left join
    a_sdo_geometry_tbl b
    on a.line_id = b.line_id
order by
    a.line_id,
    a.vertex_id
```